# Why is this WinRT function required to be extracted while others are not?

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime

At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-app-prelaunch#detect-and-handle-prelaunch it reads:

> Note the `TryEnablePrelaunch()` function, above. The reason the call to `CoreApplication.EnablePrelaunch()` is factored out into this function is because when a method is called, the JIT (just in time compilation) will attempt to compile the entire method. If your app is running on a version of Windows 10 that doesn't support `CoreApplication.EnablePrelaunch()`, then the JIT will fail. By factoring the call into a method that is only called when the app determines that the platform supports `CoreApplication.EnablePrelaunch()`, we avoid that problem.

Why is this fuss necessary here while it doesn't seem necessary at [all other occasions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code#adaptive-code-examples)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's outdated guidance from the WinPhone days. It was necessary to break calls into separate methods so you could catch the MissingMethod exception.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is always important to make sure if the API is available on a device. The note in the first document emphasized the reason why you should not use an API that is not available in the current OS version. The second document gives a summary about this and shows the common ways to check API availability.

Both of them are telling the importance of API availability.

Comment: But it is necessary to extract such call into a separate function only for `CoreApplication.EnablePrelaunch()`? All other examples in the documentation just call a WinRT function (after checking its availability), they never extract them into a separate funciton.

Comment: It just explains a way to do that and the reason why to do that. You could do the same for other functions as well. The key point is that it is important to do the API availability check for APIs that might not support all versions.

Comment: I still don't get it. If it's necessary to encapsulate *all* WinRT functions into separate functions because otherwise a method containing the call wouldn't be compiled by the JIT compiler (why is JIT compiling involved here anyway?) that would become rather cumbersome over time, or the app would simply crash on older Windows versions. And then, the API check would be redundant anyway. ... Where's my fallacy?

Comment: First, not all APIs need to do the API availability check. Second, The way to put a method into a separate function is optional. You could directly call this API. Because the key step- API availability check is done in the first. All you need to do is check the result to see if the device could be able to run the target API.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. OK, that's what I believed so far. ... Then *why* is this fuss around extracing `CoreApplication.EnablePrelaunch()` necessary then? What's so special with `CoreApplication.EnablePrelaunch()` that it needs to be extracted into a separate method (or, otherwise, the program will crash, regardless of the previous check, because even the check won't be run)?

Comment: You could directly try to use it on a device that does not support this API to see the result. In the document, you could see whether the separated method is called depends on the result of the API availability check which is done in the beginning. Put the API in a sparated method is optional, it shows a different way about how you call a method and the note shows the benefit of this way. You could use it or not. It depends on your willing.

Comment: Thank you again, Roy. So, if it is indeed unnecessary to extract a WinRT function into separate methods (which would be hell to do, anyway), what's the exact meaning of ... *"The reason the call to CoreApplication.EnablePrelaunch() is factored out into this function is because when a method is called, the JIT (just in time compilation) will attempt to compile the entire method. If your app is running on a version of Windows 10 that doesn't support CoreApplication.EnablePrelaunch(), then the JIT will fail."* ? ...... What's a "JIT"??? What's exactly happening when it "fails"?

Comment: Well, JIT is the just-in-time compiler. It will translate the intermediate language into native code. When it fails, the app will crash.